# Transfer WETH from myetherwallet to metamask wallet

Tags: ether, metamask, myetherwallet

I converted some of my ETH to WETH already, on my hardware wallet. H/w wallet was conected to myetherwallet, and I can see my WETH there under tokens panel.

I also created a metamask wallet and I am looking to transfer WETH over there. But  I can't get a deposit address for WETH on metamask even after adding WETH in tokens. I tried with some other ERC-20 tokens as well, but can't see deposit address for those other tokens as well. I only see a deposit address for ETH.

How do I get my WETH to metamask wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply send the tokens to your Ethereum address. There is no specific token deposit address for wallets like MetaMask. Don't send the tokens to the token contract address, because in that case they will get locked up.

For wallets where you own the private keys (like MetaMask), you can send ETH and tokens to the same address. For other wallets (like exchanges), you usually have to send the tokens to a specific token address.